# Angular JS ui-router's state in modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here's the '[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/W0ZXamyD1jcpFGPCG0fs?p=preview)'  to describe the situation.

1. The main page (home.html) consists of four <ui-view>s: graph, fields, modal and configure.
2. The *graph* <ui-view> is for the graph section.
3. The *fields* <ui-view> displays fields (fields.html and fields2.html) depending upon the links user clicks on.
4. The *modal* <ui-view> displays the modal dialog.
5. The *configure* <ui-view> displays the list of settings to be set on the dialog.

The problem I am facing is - how to persist the state of the ***fields*** <ui-view> the user has left before she clicks on the configure link to open the dialog?

**EDIT**: Also I am not able to display the settings (settings1.html, settings2.html, settings3.html) pages on the dialog on click of the dialog links.
Here's the code for routes.js:

```
angular.module("myApp")
  .config(["$stateProvider", function($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
          .state("home", {
              url: "/",
              templateUrl: "home.html"
           })
           .state("home.dashboard", {
                views: {
                    "graph": {
                         templateUrl: "graph.html"
                     },
                     "fields": {
                         templateUrl: "fields.html"
                     }
                }
           })
          .state("home.moreFields", {
              views: {
                  "graph": {
                       templateUrl: "graph.html"
                   },
                   "fields": {
                       templateUrl: "fields2.html"
                   }
              }
          })
          .state("home.configure", {
              views: {
                  "graph": {
                       templateUrl: "graph.html"
                   },
                   "fields": {
                       // The templateUrl might be 'fields1.html' or 'fields2.html' depending upon    link the user clicked at the time when the dialog is opened.
                   },
                   "modal": {
                        templateUrl: "configure.html"
                   }
              }
          })
         .state("home.configure.settings1", {
             views: {
                 "graph": {},
                 "fields": {},
                 "configure": {
                     templateUrl: "settings1.html"
             }        
          }
      })
      .state("home.configure.settings2", {
           views: {
               "configure": {
                   templateUrl: "settings2.html"
                }
           }
      })
     .state("home.configure.settings3", {
         views: {
             "configure": {
                 templateUrl: "settings3.html"
             }
         }
      });
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at UI-Router extras and particularly [Sticky States](https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky) in order to preserve your state and scope. From what I understand, it fits your requirements perfectly.

For your home.configure state fields template you can use a function to return you the appropriate template as described in the official [UIRouter wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

```
"fields": {
  templateUrl: function ($stateParams){
    return '/partials/field.' + $stateParams.clickedFieldNumber + '.html';
  }
}
```